# My Asp.Net API (on Plesk) stops responding when I deploy the Blazor Web-Assembly project on the same server

Tags: asp.net-web-api, blazor-webassembly, plesk

My Web API working fine with all other projects (ASP.Net Core, .Net App). But when I deploy the Blazor webassembly Project on the same server, my  API stops responding.
After that, the API was not even responding to Post-Man.
Note: My API is published in the virtual directory.